# Проблема с чтением файла и записью информации в mapHash

Tags: java, файлы

Задание звучит так: "Загрузите данные из файла в эту карту одним потоком. Убедись в том, что данные в созданной карте были отсортированы по длине строки key (да, это будет довольно большой поток с множеством операций). Значения NA заменить нулями.". Проблема заключается в том что я не могу записать значение с текстового файла в mapHash. Выдает

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=60443:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\Project\out\production\Project com.company.Main

Есть подозрение что это не отвечает заданию, если так и есть то помогите пожалуйста еще и сделать так что-бы отвечало заданию (один поток с большим количеством операций)

Класс Animal

```
package com.company;
import java.io.*;
public class Animal {
    //public String species;
    public double body_wt;
    public double brain_wt;
    public double non_dreaming;
    public double dreaming;
    public double total_sleep;
    public double life_span;
    public double gestation;
    public int predation;
    public int exposure;
    public int danger;
}
```

Main

```
package com.company;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    final static String filePath = "C:/Users/User/IdeaProjects/Project";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here

        //Animal animal = new Animal();
       Map<String, Animal> hMapFile = new HashMap<String, Animal>();

    }


    public static Map<String, Animal> getHashMapFromTextFile(){

        Animal animal = new Animal();
        Map<String, Animal> hMapContens = new HashMap<String, Animal>();
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try{
            File file = new File(filePath);
            //создание BufferedReader обьекта с файла
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line = null;

            //read file line by line
            while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null ){


                String[] parts = line.split(";");

                String species = parts[0].trim();
                animal.body_wt = Double.parseDouble(parts[1].trim());
                animal.brain_wt = Double.parseDouble(parts[2].trim());
                animal.non_dreaming = Double.parseDouble(parts[3].trim());
                animal.dreaming = Double.parseDouble(parts[4].trim());
                animal.total_sleep = Double.parseDouble(parts[5].trim());
                animal.life_span = Double.parseDouble(parts[6].trim());
                animal.gestation = Double.parseDouble(parts[7].trim());
                animal.predation = Integer.parseInt(parts[8].trim());
                animal.exposure = Integer.parseInt(parts[9].trim());
                animal.exposure = Integer.parseInt(parts[10].trim());
                //put name, age in HashMap if they are not empty
                if( species != "" && animal.body_wt != 0 && animal.brain_wt != 0 && animal.non_dreaming != 0 && animal.dreaming != 0
                        && animal.total_sleep != 0 && animal.life_span != 0 && animal.gestation != 0 && animal.predation != 0
                        && animal.exposure != 0 && animal.danger != 0)
                {
                    String temp1 = Double.toString(animal.body_wt),
                            temp2 = Double.toString(animal.brain_wt),
                            temp3 = Double.toString(animal.non_dreaming),
                            temp4 = Double.toString(animal.dreaming),
                            temp5 = Double.toString(animal.total_sleep),
                            temp6 = Double.toString(animal.life_span),
                            temp7 = Double.toString(animal.gestation),
                            temp8 = Integer.toString(animal.predation),
                            temp9 = Integer.toString(animal.exposure),
                            temp10 = Integer.toString(animal.danger);
                    if(temp1 == "NA") {animal.body_wt = 0;};
                    if(temp2 == "NA") {animal.brain_wt = 0;};
                    if(temp3 == "NA") {animal.non_dreaming = 0;};
                    if(temp4 == "NA") {animal.dreaming = 0;};
                    if(temp5 == "NA") {animal.total_sleep = 0;};
                    if(temp6 == "NA") {animal.life_span = 0;};
                    if(temp7 == "NA") {animal.gestation = 0;};
                    if(temp8 == "NA") {animal.predation = 0;};
                    if(temp9 == "NA") {animal.exposure = 0;};
                    if(temp10 == "NA") {animal.danger = 0;};
                    hMapContens.put(species,animal);
                }

            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{

            //Always close the BufferedReader
            if(br != null){
                try {
                    br.close();
                }catch(Exception e){};
            }
        }

        int a = hMapContens.size();
        System.out.println(a);
        return hMapContens;
    }
}
```

Текстовый файл

```
species;body_wt;brain_wt;non_dreaming;dreaming;total_sleep;life_span;gestation;predation;exposure;danger
Africanelephant;6654;5712;NA;NA;3.3;38.6;645;3;5;3
Africangiantpouchedrat;1;6.6;6.3;2;8.3;4.5;42;3;1;3
ArcticFox;3.385;44.5;NA;NA;12.5;14;60;1;1;1
Arcticgroundsquirrel;0.92;5.7;NA;NA;16.5;NA;25;5;2;3
Asianelephant;2547;4603;2.1;1.8;3.9;69;624;3;5;4
Baboon;10.55;179.5;9.1;0.7;9.8;27;180;4;4;4
Bigbrownbat;0.023;0.3;15.8;3.9;19.7;19;35;1;1;1
Braziliantapir;160;169;5.2;1;6.2;30.4;392;4;5;4
Cat;3.3;25.6;10.9;3.6;14.5;28;63;1;2;1
Chimpanzee;52.16;440;8.3;1.4;9.7;50;230;1;1;1
Chinchilla;0.425;6.4;11;1.5;12.5;7;112;5;4;4
Cow;465;423;3.2;0.7;3.9;30;281;5;5;5
Deserthedgehog;0.55;2.4;7.6;2.7;10.3;NA;NA;2;1;2
Donkey;187.1;419;NA;NA;3.1;40;365;5;5;5
EasternAmericanmole;0.075;1.2;6.3;2.1;8.4;3.5;42;1;1;1
Echidna;3;25;8.6;0;8.6;50;28;2;2;2
Europeanhedgehog;0.785;3.5;6.6;4.1;10.7;6;42;2;2;2
Galago;0.2;5;9.5;1.2;10.7;10.4;120;2;2;2
Genet;1.41;17.5;4.8;1.3;6.1;34;NA;1;2;1
Giantarmadillo;60;81;12;6.1;18.1;7;NA;1;1;1
Giraffe;529;680;NA;0.3;NA;28;400;5;5;5
Goat;27.66;115;3.3;0.5;3.8;20;148;5;5;5
Goldenhamster;0.12;1;11;3.4;14.4;3.9;16;3;1;2
Gorilla;207;406;NA;NA;12;39.3;252;1;4;1
Grayseal;85;325;4.7;1.5;6.2;41;310;1;3;1
Graywolf;36.33;119.5;NA;NA;13;16.2;63;1;1;1
Groundsquirrel;0.101;4;10.4;3.4;13.8;9;28;5;1;3
Guineapig;1.04;5.5;7.4;0.8;8.2;7.6;68;5;3;4
Horse;521;655;2.1;0.8;2.9;46;336;5;5;5
Jaguar;100;157;NA;NA;10.8;22.4;100;1;1;1
Kangaroo;35;56;NA;NA;NA;16.3;33;3;5;4
Lessershort-tailedshrew;0.005;0.14;7.7;1.4;9.1;2.6;21.5;5;2;4
Littlebrownbat;0.01;0.25;17.9;2;19.9;24;50;1;1;1
Man;62;1320;6.1;1.9;8;100;267;1;1;1
Molerat;0.122;3;8.2;2.4;10.6;NA;30;2;1;1
Mountainbeaver;1.35;8.1;8.4;2.8;11.2;NA;45;3;1;3
Mouse;0.023;0.4;11.9;1.3;13.2;3.2;19;4;1;3
Muskshrew;0.048;0.33;10.8;2;12.8;2;30;4;1;3
NAmericanopossum;1.7;6.3;13.8;5.6;19.4;5;12;2;1;1
Nine-bandedarmadillo;3.5;10.8;14.3;3.1;17.4;6.5;120;2;1;1
Okapi;250;490;NA;1;NA;23.6;440;5;5;5
Owlmonkey;0.48;15.5;15.2;1.8;17;12;140;2;2;2
Patasmonkey;10;115;10;0.9;10.9;20.2;170;4;4;4
Phanlanger;1.62;11.4;11.9;1.8;13.7;13;17;2;1;2
Pig;192;180;6.5;1.9;8.4;27;115;4;4;4
Rabbit;2.5;12.1;7.5;0.9;8.4;18;31;5;5;5
Raccoon;4.288;39.2;NA;NA;12.5;13.7;63;2;2;2
Rat;0.28;1.9;10.6;2.6;13.2;4.7;21;3;1;3
Redfox;4.235;50.4;7.4;2.4;9.8;9.8;52;1;1;1
Rhesusmonkey;6.8;179;8.4;1.2;9.6;29;164;2;3;2
Rockhyrax(Heterob);0.75;12.3;5.7;0.9;6.6;7;225;2;2;2
Rockhyrax(Procaviahab);3.6;21;4.9;0.5;5.4;6;225;3;2;3
Roedeer;14.83;98.2;NA;NA;2.6;17;150;5;5;5
Sheep;55.5;175;3.2;0.6;3.8;20;151;5;5;5
Slowloris;1.4;12.5;NA;NA;11;12.7;90;2;2;2
Starnosedmole;0.06;1;8.1;2.2;10.3;3.5;NA;3;1;2
Tenrec;0.9;2.6;11;2.3;13.3;4.5;60;2;1;2
Treehyrax;2;12.3;4.9;0.5;5.4;7.5;200;3;1;3
Treeshrew;0.104;2.5;13.2;2.6;15.8;2.3;46;3;2;2
Vervet;4.19;58;9.7;0.6;10.3;24;210;4;3;4
Wateropossum;3.5;3.9;12.8;6.6;19.4;3;14;2;1;1
Yellow-belliedmarmot;4.05;17;NA;NA;NA;13;38;3;1;1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Непонятно, что означает сортировка по длине строки key, потому как нигде не упоминается ничего с названием key, вместе с тем, чтобы спарсить файл, не используя никаких дополнительных библиотек (не считая lombok, который парсером не является по определению и нужен лишь длся того, чтобы не писать стандартный код), лучше написать что-то универсальное. Например , так:

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class FileReader<T> {

    private final String delimeter;

    private final String charset;

    private final Class<T> clazz;

    public FileReader(final Class<T> clazz, String delimeter, String charset) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.delimeter = delimeter;
        this.charset = charset;
    }

    public List<T> loadCSV(final String path) {
        try {
            final List<String> rows = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path), Charset.forName(charset));
            final String[] columnsNames = rows.remove(0).split(delimeter);
            final List<T> valuesList = new ArrayList<>(rows.size());

            for (final String v : rows) {
                final String[] value = v.split(delimeter);
                final Map<String, String> values = new LinkedHashMap(value.length);
                for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) values.put(columnsNames[i], value[i]);
                final T t = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(Map.class).newInstance(values);
                valuesList.add(t);
            }
            return valuesList;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

}

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;

@lombok.Data
public class Animal {

    private String species;
    private Double bodyWt;
    private Double brainWt;
    private Double nonDreaming;
    private Double dreaming;
    private Double totalSleep;
    private Double lifeSpan;
    private Double gestation;
    private Integer predation;
    private Integer exposure;
    private Integer danger;

    public Animal(Map<String,String> values) {
        this.species = parse(values, "species", s->s);
        this.bodyWt = parse(values, "body_wt", Double::valueOf);
        this.brainWt = parse(values, "brain_wt", Double::valueOf);
        this.nonDreaming = parse(values, "non_dreaming", Double::valueOf);
        this.dreaming = parse(values, "dreaming", Double::valueOf);
        this.totalSleep = parse(values, "total_sleep", Double::valueOf);
        this.lifeSpan = parse(values, "life_span", Double::valueOf);
        this.gestation = parse(values, "gestation", Double::valueOf);
        this.predation = parse(values, "predation", Integer::valueOf);
        this.exposure = parse(values, "exposure", Integer::valueOf);
        this.danger = parse(values, "danger", Integer::valueOf);
    }
    
    private static <R> R parse(Map<String,String> values, String fieldName, Function <String,R> converter) {
        final String fieldValue = values.get(fieldName);
        return fieldValue==null || "NA".equals(fieldValue) ? null : converter.apply(fieldValue);
    }
        
}

import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileReader<Animal> fileReader = new FileReader(Animal.class, ";", "UTF-8");
        List <Animal>result = fileReader.loadCSV("test.txt");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    
}
```

Разумеется, можно написать свою аннотацию и заставить сам парсер записывать в поля класса значения с помощью рефлексии. Кроме того, можно сделать родительский класс для классов-моделей, в котором добавить конструктор, принимающий map, написать простьйшие методы вроде parseDouble, что упростит конструктор модели, но это уже зависит от вашей задачи.

Comment: Хорошо спасибо и key это species

Comment: @Yanok тогда это довольно просто реализовать. просто добавьте в метод main такую строку result.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(v -> v.getSpecies().length()));

Comment: Хорошо спасибо большое

Comment: Я не могу найти файл build.gradle в IntelliJ Studio. Это может быть из-за того что приложения не на андроид? Если да то как можно эту программу переделать что-бы она была не на андроид. (И важное уточнение к проекту что species (в Animal) не должно быть как переменная в классе Animal)

Comment: @Yanok причем здесь вообще андроид? этот код написан на java, а gradle - система автоматической сборки. он вообще никакого отношения к этому коду не имеет в принципе (как и к андроиду). хотите градловский проект - создавайте его (можете с помощью идеи), копируйте приведенный выше код и будет вам джавовский проект с градловскм сборщиком. хотите - используйте мавен или создавайте андроидовский проект (правда там мавен с ангдроидом не сработает). что касается использования коллекции map - плохая идея, ведь она не может хранить дубликаты, можете получить странный результат.